# Indy TIdUDPServer component OnUDPRead - Remote IP?

Tags: delphi-xe3, indy10

Ok, this might sound stupid and pretty obvious, but I just can't get through it nor find any useful info on the web (I most likely don't know the right words to search with...)

But..

Is there a way to get the Remote IP on action ServerUDPRead on TIdUDPServer component?
I'm sending packets from the server to the same port of two different machines, so to 2 IPs, and get replies to the same server component from both of them; Now the issue is how to identify where each reply came from; Is there a way to read this from the packet itself, or would I need to implement the second TIdUDPServer component instead, and send packets to each of the destination machines separately..? 
(Note: the machine replies back to my app to the same port where the packet was sent from. So, binded port is the one that needs to be read);

Cheers

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnUDPRead` event handler has an `ABinding` parameter.  The sender's IP is in the `ABinding.PeerIP` property.

Comment: I've tried the .IP but didn't get what I needed... So thought the ABinding has server component's data only...
Will try PeerIP asap and report. Thanks!

Comment: `ABinding.IP` is the local IP that `TIdUDPServer` is receiving on. `ABinding.PeerIP` is the remote IP of the sender.